# How to aggregate Python dataframe calculating a rate

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Initially I have a dataframe like this:

```
GERENCY RESI1
2       -1
4       -1
4        1
5        1
6       -1
4       -1
2        1
6       -1
6        1
6       -1
...
```

I need to aggregate the values to obtain something like this:

```
GERENCY   RATE
2         28/362
3         6/215
4         11/146
5         49/612
6         38/628
```

Where the numerator is the number of rows with `RESI1 == 1` and the divisor is the total number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

Let us check `groupby` with `mean`

```
out = df['RESI1'].eq(1).groupby(df['GERENCY']).mean().to_frame('RATE').reset_index()
Out[66]: 
   GERENCY      RATE
0        2  0.500000
1        4  0.333333
2        5  1.000000
3        6  0.250000
```